# Spring security returns 401 unauthorized code for authenticated users trying access protectd resource instead of 403 access denied

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I declared two protected endpoints `forAdmin()` and `forUser()` for users with User and Admin roles respectively. When an admin user is authenticated, they can access `forAdmin()`. Also, a user with the user role can access `forUser()` when authenticated. But if an admin tries to access `forUser()` resource, the application would return `401 unauthorization` meaning the user has yet to be authenticated, instead of  `403 access denied`. I would like to know how to fix this please.

`config files:`

```
@Configuration
//@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
    private CustomUserDetailsService jwtService;
    
    private static final String[] ALLOWED_ACCESS = {"/authenticate", "/registerNewUser"};

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint,
            JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter, CustomUserDetailsService jwtService) {

        this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint = jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {

        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable()).cors(cors -> {
        }).authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> {
            authz.requestMatchers("/forAdmin").hasRole("Admin");
            authz.requestMatchers("/forUser").hasRole("User");
            authz.requestMatchers(ALLOWED_ACCESS).permitAll();
            
        })
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(
                        (exceptionHandling) -> {
                            exceptionHandling.accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler());
                            exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);
                            
                        })
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
    
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
         authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
        
}
```

Authentication entry point:

```
@Configuration
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");

    }

}
```

Access denied:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

`Filter class:`

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    private CustomUserDetailsService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    public JwtRequestFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil, CustomUserDetailsService jwtService) {

        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {

            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            } catch (SignatureException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid token");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("JWT token does not start with Bearer");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = jwtService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

Protected resource:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping({"/forAdmin"})
    //@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Admin')")
    public String forAdmin() {
        
        return "You're an Admin";
    }
    
    @GetMapping({"/forUser"})
    //@PreAuthorize("hasRole('User')")
    public String forUser() {
        
        return "You're a user";
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: Using jwts as session is dangerous and writing custom security filters is bad practice. Whatever blogpost you have followed has no idea how security works. Please read the spring security docs

Comment: Please explain to me how writing custom security filters is bad practice. You mean extending a base class such as OncePerRequestFilter is bad practice?

Comment: No as i wrote, using jwts as sessions is insecure. There is no such filter already in spring security just because using jwts as sessions is very insecure. But you instead wrote a custom filter so that you could use a jwt as a session. Jwts where never meant to used as a session, for that you use cookies. You only need to google why jwts shouldnt be used as sessions to understand why. Stop using jwts the way you are doing and instead use formlogin from spring security and read the documentation instead of poor blogposts